# Ajax keyup event doesn't work after render

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have problem with JSF and Ajax. I used Ajax keyup event to filter selectOneListbox. It's working fine if I render all on start. When I hide panel with this component and render it when I select appropriate option in selectOneRadio, keyup event doesn't work.

JSF code:

```
<h:form id="form">

    Client type: <h:selectOneRadio id="client_type" value="#{testBean.clientType}" styleClass="radio">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="N" itemLabel="New client" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="Existing client" />
        <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="clientPanel" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>

    <br /><br />

    <h:panelGroup id="clientPanel">

        <h:panelGroup id="existedClient" rendered="#{testBean.clientType eq 'E'}">

            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Existed client</p>

            Search: <h:inputText id="in" value="#{testBean.clientSearchPattern}" autocomplete="off">
                <f:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{testBean.clientChanged}" render="client_select" />
            </h:inputText>

            Client: <h:selectOneListbox id="client_select" value="#{testBean.complaint.client.id}" required="true"
                                        style="width: 200px; font-family: 'Ubuntu'; font-size: 14.6667px; font-style: normal;">
                <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.clients}" var="client"
                               itemLabel="#{client.name} #{client.surname}" itemValue="#{client.id}" />
            </h:selectOneListbox>

        </h:panelGroup>

        <br /><br />

        <h:panelGroup id="newClient" rendered="#{testBean.clientType eq 'N'}">

            <p style="font-weight: bold;">New client</p>

            Name: <h:inputText id="name" value="#{testBean.clientSearchPattern}" />

        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

Java code:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {

@Inject
private ClientService clientService;

private String clientType = "N";
private String clientSearchPattern;
private List<Client> clients;

private Complaint complaint = new Complaint();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    clients = clientService.list();
}

public void clientChanged() {
    clients = clientService.search(clientSearchPattern);
}

public String getClientSearchPattern() {
    return clientSearchPattern;
}

public void setClientSearchPattern(String clientSearchPattern) {
    this.clientSearchPattern = clientSearchPattern;
}

public List<Client> getClients() {
    return clients;
}

public Complaint getComplaint() {
    return complaint;
}

public void setComplaint(Complaint complaint) {
    this.complaint = complaint;
}

public String getClientType() {
    return clientType;
}

public void setClientType(String clientType) {
    this.clientType = clientType;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: with no exceptions being throwed?

Comment: Have you tried simply disabling the element until the proper option is selected?

Comment: No exceptions, no messages, nothing. Disabling working fine, but I must save space on the page. Therefore I want to hide elements. I solved this by adding conditional styleClass with "display: none" style, but it isn't elegant solution.